# JavaScript API Drive Uploader - Upload file manually using JS

Tags: javascript, file-upload, google-drive-api

I am using drive uploader component (https://driveuploader.com/) in my application to upload files on GoogleDrive. It is workign fine as long as the user selects file using the component. Now the new requirement needs me to upload the file manually using JavaScript. I will be given bytes array and then I need to convert that bytes array to file and then upload it to google drive using driveuploader and the further process goes on as is, but I am not able to come up with the idea how to do it. Any pointer in this regard are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot understand about `upload the file manually using JavaScript`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanika I will make AJAX call and in return I will be receiving bytes array. Now I want to upload that bytes array as file to google drive. I am using DriveUploader for uploading files to drive and it only works if user selects and uploads the file using the interface

Comment: Thank you for replying. For your replying, I have 3 questions. 1. In your goal, which do you want to make users upload a file to user's Google Drive or your Google Drive? I cannot understand about the destination Google Drive. 2. Where do you want to put the HTML & Javascript for uploading a file? 3. Can you provide your current script and the current issue of it?

Comment: 1. File is uploaded on to the application's service account.
2. For HTML & JS, I am using driveuploader. It suggests you create a simple div and apply class 'driveuploader-replace' to that div. When JS library is uploaded, it will automatically create all the necessary HTML.
3. Scripts that are used can be found at this link: "https://driveuploader.com/upload/{uploader key}/embed.js"

Comment: Actually that is my problem. Everything is done automatically and I do not have much control over it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to upload a file to Google Drive of the service account using the service account. In that case, you don't want to use "driveuploader" and want to use HTML and Javascript. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I want to use driveuploader functionality but not by UI but by using JS.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I cannot understand about your goal. So I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand about it, I would like to think of the issue and solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: @Tanika thank you for discussing the problem with me. Its all one can hope for from a community. I truly appreciate your help. Just for info, I ended up writing a server side code for handling the File upload and decided not to go with driveruploader functionality.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I ended up writing a server side code for handling the File upload and decided not to go with driveruploader functionality`, if you have the issue for this, can I ask you about your current issue?

Comment: @Tanaike it's working fine. Thank you for offering your help.